# Public Sub to switch between two forms

Tags: vb.net

I have this Public Sub that I am trying to use on a menu strip. Instead of switching forms, it opens another instance of the frmEmployee form. The Employee Form opens first. How would I hide the open form and open the other form? Thanks!

```
Public Sub SwitchForm()
    Dim F1 As New frmEmployee
    Dim F2 As New frmEvaluation
    If F1.Visible = True Then
        F1.Hide()
        F2.Show()
    Else
        F2.Hide()
        F1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A) Add `Option Strict On`  to the top of your code files B) Read about Scope - *where* you declare something determines its scope.  You declare those form vars in the method so thats the only place they reside which leads you to create new ones incorrectly. C) Read [ask] and take the [tour] D) Profit!

Comment: Why do you need a method (Sub or function) to change forms?  Cant each form just open/show the *other* one?  Modified to work, that code runs the risk of a NullReferenceException - aside from not Visible, the object vars can be not yet instantiated.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am looking into scopes and fixing my current mistakes.

Comment: Is either `frmEmployee` or `frmEvaluation` the startup object for the application?

Comment: frmEmployee is my main form that opens when I start my program. frmEvaluation does not open at all.  Under my project properties, the Startup form is set to frmEmployees, but I'm not sure if that is the startup object?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your variables `F1` and `F2` inside the scope of your function. So every time you call that function, it will create two new instances of those forms, and checking `F1.Visible` is pointless because it won't refer to the old instance but to the one you just created.

Comment: While you have correctly pointed out a problem with the code in the question, this isn't really an answer unless you explain how to fix it.

Comment: Yup, you have to explain object-oriented programming to somebody that doesn't have the first clue what it means.  Good luck.

Comment: Its true, I don't know anything. I'm just trying to pass a class and learn in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to play with...

```
Public Class frmEmployee

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SwitchForm()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class frmEvaluation

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SwitchForm()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmEvaluation_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        e.Cancel = True
        SwitchForm()
    End Sub

End Class

Module Module1

    Public Sub SwitchForm()
        Dim curForm As Form = Form.ActiveForm
        Form.ActiveForm.Hide()
        If curForm Is frmEmployee Then
            Dim eval As Form = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmEvaluation).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(eval) Then
                eval.Show()
            Else
                eval = New frmEvaluation
                eval.Show()
            End If
        Else
            Dim emp As Form = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmEmployee).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(emp) Then
                emp.Show() ' should always be able to show this form as it is the startup object
            Else
                ' ...shouldn't be able to get here...
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer.

This is an example that seems to work for me. You might need to tweak it depending on how your forms are declared and created, but it works for me ..

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents frm1 As New Form
    Dim WithEvents frm2 As New Form

    Dim formWithFocus As String = ""

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        frm1.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        frm1.Size = New Size(100, 100)
        frm1.Name = "frm1"
        frm2.Location = New Point(200, 200)
        frm2.Size = frm1.Size
        frm2.Name = "frm2"
        frm1.Show()
        frm2.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frm_gotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frm1.GotFocus, frm2.GotFocus
        If sender Is frm1 Then
            formWithFocus = "frm1"
        ElseIf sender Is frm2 Then
            formWithFocus = "frm2"
        End If
        formWithFocus = CType(sender, Form).Name
    End Sub

    Private Sub switchform()
        If formWithFocus = "frm1" Then
            RemoveHandler frm1.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            RemoveHandler frm2.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            frm2.Select()
            formWithFocus = "frm2"
            AddHandler frm1.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            AddHandler frm2.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
        ElseIf formWithFocus = "frm2" Then
            RemoveHandler frm1.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            RemoveHandler frm2.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            frm1.Select()
            formWithFocus = "frm1"
            AddHandler frm1.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
            AddHandler frm2.GotFocus, AddressOf frm_gotFocus
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        switchform()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I ended up doing this to save time. I just wanted to know if there was some simple way I could have coded one Sub to determine which form was open, hide that form, and open the form that was not open.

Comment: @Merskies Have a look at my updated answer This might be better suited to your needs

Comment: _I just wanted to know if there was some simple way I could have coded one Sub to determine which form was open, hide that form, and open the form that was not open._  That's what my code does...did you try it?

Comment: @Idle_Mind No. However, The stack site suggests that if we have an answer that is a different approach, we should write it as our own answer. It may suit the users needs better. This is a different approach. No offence intended at all. My comment that it might better suit the op's needs was only in reference to my original answer.

Comment: Hehe...sorry David. My comment was directed at Merskies.  Nothing wrong with your approach at all.  =)